# Solving Maxwell Equations when a charge is put inside a generic conductor

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, maxwell-equations

A net point-charge density $\rho_0$ is impressed without speed (no impressed current density) at position **r0** at time $t_0$. Relaxation analysis tells us the charge density will decrease exponentially because charges tend to separate them and locate on the material surface.

I'm curious about not just evaluating the charge density, but the overall expression of electric and magnetic fields. Let's write all the equations we know for this problem inside the medium, which is assumed to be linear, homogeneous, non-dispersive, and isotropic:

[image]

Placing the Gauss Law for E and the Ohm Law inside the Charge Conservation Equation we get a first-order partial differential equation with an exponential solution (charge relaxation):

$$\frac{σ}{ϵ} ρ(r,t)+\frac{∂}{∂t} ρ(r,t)=0$$

$$ρ(r,t)=ρ(r,t_0 )⋅e^{-\frac{t-t_0}{\frac{ϵ}{σ}}}$$

Now let's try to evaluate the transient for E, and B (if it is too complicated, approximations are fine for me):

Known the charge density, we can find the electric potential under Lorenz Gauge:

$$∇^2 V(r,t)-ϵμ \frac{∂^2}{∂t^2} V(r,t)  =- \frac{ρ(r,t)}{ϵ}$$

Solving with Green Function in isotropic medium assuming zero potential at infinity as a reference:

[image]

Now, to find the electric field I need also the vector magnetic potential, which is unknown as I don't know the current distribution which is $\sigma \bf{E}$.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

First, I want to note that your description of the situation sounds like it violates charge conversation.  You can't just "impress" a charge at a particular location at some time $t_0$ without having a current that brought it there at times $t < t_0$.  If your goal is to model the relaxation currents that happen when a free charge moves inside a conductor, you might need to consider a different model to get mathematically sensible results.

To find the vector potential, though:  you have the term $\sigma \vec{E}$ in your equation for the vector potential.  This can be eliminated by noting that
$$
\sigma \vec{E} = - \sigma \left( \vec{\nabla} V + \frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t} \right).
$$
You can then rearrange this equation to get a wave-like equation for $\vec{A}$, with the $\vec{\nabla} V$ term acting as a source.  The $\partial \vec{A}/\partial t$ term in your new equation for $\vec{A}$ will lead to exponential damping of the solutions, rather than freely propagating waves — which is what we expect from our experience in, for example, EM waves propagating in conductors.

Comment: That's pretty much the hint I needed. Just a question about the missing impressed current in my model: should I just set its value at t0 or should I track all the history from t  in ]-infty;t0[?